# Passing Session value to a NetworkCredentials

Tags: asp.net, .net

Here is my code

```
Dir_tpWebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("us_UserName"), System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("us_Password"))
```

"System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("us_UserName")" this line of code gives an error "argument matching parameter 'username' narrows from 'object' to 'string'" anybody who has an idea with this?

Comment: donot write it in a double quote. Use single quotes. Doube quotes make it a string.

Comment: @Learner what? He just needs to convert the values to string, use .ToString or Convert.ToString: Convert.ToString(Session("us_UserName"))

Comment: I assume he is have a session variable and he needs to pass it to the network credentials.

Comment: @Esko's answer solved the issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Session` can contain just about anything, not just strings.<sup>1</sup>

Therefore, when you retrieve something from the session, it's typed as [`object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dhkksh8(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you know you're retrieving strings, you need to insert casts to tell the compiler that:

```
Dir_tpWebRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(
   CType(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("us_UserName"),String),
   CType(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("us_Password"),String))
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If you're using the in-memory provider, there's practically no limit to the types of object you can store. If you're using other providers, you're restricted to serializable objects, but it's still quite a broad range.

Comment: (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("us_UserName") using this causes shows an error "Error 54 'String' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression."

Comment: @EdwardCalusayan - if this isn't the fix then there might be more to the problem to be solved. But that suggests that we'll need more than a single line of code. Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your answer is correct but I suspect he is using VB.Net :) Anyway he got it fixed.